# Amazon Ec2 FTP Write Permission

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am able to successfully connect to amazon ec2 instance using filezilla. The Username i used is ec2-user. So when i try to transfer my application war to tomcat it says

```
/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/RealEstateERP.war: open for write: permission denied
 Error: File transfer failed.
```

I tried to change permission use filezilla but not allowed to do so. I know there is no write permission, but how do i change it.

I ma new to linux. Please help me.

Comment: Voted up. I had the exact same problem. Maybe it's off topic. Should it be on super user?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The **ec2-user** don't have permission to write files in /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/. Only **root** user can do so. You have two ways here to do so:

1) Copy files to /home/ec2-user/ using filezilla. Now SSH into linux machine through putty. Change to root user using command `sudo -s`. Then copy file from /home/ec2-user to /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/ using command `cp -i RealEstateERP.war  /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/`.

2) SSH into linux machine through putty.Change to root user using command `sudo -s`.Provide write permission to all users on /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/ using command `chmod 777 /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/`. Then copy files to directory directly from filezilla.

Comment: Can u tell me how to transfer a large size file.Actually i am not able to transfer my war. Its size is approx 22 Mb. And i am able to transfer a small size file.

Comment: have you tried using winSCP in place of filezilla.

Comment: Yes i just tries it, and transfer first hangs and then it disconnect with server.

Comment: i sometimes have this problem, but that is due to slow connection.

Comment: Why can't we just login as root then?

Comment: @JimThio it is best to run with least privileges.  You never give someone full access rights unless they absolutely need it.  Some good Wikipedia reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege

Comment: Is there anything innately insecure about option 2? It seems convenient and nice, but my gut reaction to it is to hold back.