# Tomcat on EC2. Can't write to webapps

Tags: tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

End game: Copy project directory to tomcat webapps directory hosted on ec2.

I have an amazon linux instance, I install tomcat via

```
sudo yum install tomcat7-webapps
```

When I first ssh in I am led to a home folder. From there I must cd twice, then proceed to

```
/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps
```

I tried to transfer the directory using filezilla, but I don't have write permissions here.. also attempted to change the permissions but it's not allowed. Should I have installed tomcat to my home directory perhaps?

I also tried to set up a repository with git but running git init failed as it couldn't write.

Read about scp, could I use that to transfer the entire directory?

Any help here is much appreciated! I read a ton of older posts but nothings working for me.

- importing pem to filezilla, set up as sftp user:ec2-user

**EDIT: I have sorted it out! My solution:**

Find where tomcat was installed, in my case

```
/var/lib/tomcat7
```

and run the following:

```
sudo usermod -a -G tomcat7 ec2-user
sudo chmod -R g+w /var/lib/tomcat7
```

I found this question being asked a ton, so I hope this helps anyone with this problem in the future! Give this guy a vote if it helps. [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020622/how-to-upload-a-lib-for-tomcat-in-amazon-ec2)