# Transferring files to AWS instance using FileZilla

Tags: amazon-web-services, sftp, filezilla

FileZilla throws errors when trying to connect to AWS instance via SFTP mode. Instance is running on Ubuntu 13.10.

```
Error:  Connection refused
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

Connection params:

```
Host: XX.XX.X.XXX
Username: ubuntu
Port: 22
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved: seems that my instance was glitchy. Terminated the old one and create new. Working now.

Answer (score 0):

By default the Security groups keeps all the ports closed. You need to enable the SFTP port in the security group: [Amazon EC2 Security Groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html)

Another, thing is to ensure an SFTP server is running on the instance (you can login/SSH to the instance and try connecting SFTP locally and check this).

Answer (score 0):

Open the appropriate inbound port in your Security Group as described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html).

Import the .pem [key pair](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html) associated to your EC2 instance into FileZilla.

The way to access your instance is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16744863/connect-to-amazon-ec2-file-directory-using-filezilla-and-sftp/17134004#17134004).

Comment: Did it at the very first time, but it is not the problem + the SSH has been added to security group as well...