# SSH-key copy without login

Tags: ssh-keys

I'm faced with the typical problem of having created an ssh key on a client and wanting to update the server's authorized_keys to contain the new client's public key.

From searching the forums I have seen many suggestions to use scp or ssh-copy-id.

However, both of these require login to the server.
For security reasons, I would prefer not accepting any password login on my server, so I'm looking for a way to communicate the client's public key to the server without login.

So first question: Is there an accepted method for this?

I was thinking about using the SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND variable so that the client would do something like

```
ssh dummy@server `cat mykey.pub`
```

and in the server I would be able to use the logs to see the connection attempt (and failure since the key is unknown) and copy the original command.
However, I have seen that in /var/log/secure, the connection attempt and failure are logged, but the command sent with it is not.

Which leads to the second question: Is this information logged in any other log?

If not, I had the idea of creating a user (let's say "dummy") on the server who would use its .ssh/authorized_keys to specify a forced command for all login attempts.  I have already seen that doing this gives me indeed access to the SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND variable, which I can write to a file somewhere.  The problem here is that I can only specify a forced command for a specific public key... but I would need to do it for **any** key.

So third question: is it possible to specify in authorized_keys a command for **any** key?

If not, my last solution is to indeed accept a password connection for user dummy on the server, but make sure the user cannot do **anything** other than calling my script with an argument (the public key) in order to ensure security.

Is this possible?

Comment: You could set the shell for the `dummy` user to your command.

Comment: You could login via a key instead of a password, plenty of sftp clients allow this and are easy to work with

Comment: Also why would you want to allow people to add keys to accounts, without logging in? That is pretty much as bad as setting each password to `password`.

Comment: @Thom, I don't want to allow people to add keys to my server, I want to "see" this key on my server somewhere, so that I can manually copy it and, after verification, add it to my authorized_keys.

Comment: @user2813274 could you please elaborate?

Comment: like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17134004/2813274) for example

Comment: @user2813274 thanks for your input but I don't see how it applies.  In the thread you link to they are talking about a solution with a GUI - that's not what I want - and with a correct setup of ssh key pairs...which is exactly what I do not have and cannot have, because my problem is to send the public key to the server in the first place!