# How to upload files in ec2 instance using windows n putty?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created an ec2 instance and connected this instance with putty. But now i have confused to how to upload files or web pages on that instance

Answer (score 1):

You can install [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php) or [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) in windows and upload the files. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16744863/connect-to-amazon-ec2-file-directory-using-filezilla-and-sftp) stackoverflow question and answer for additional details in authenticating to the ec2 instance.