# Connecting to Amazon EC2 using Filezilla SFTP - Network error: Connection refused

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, filezilla

I am completely new to Amazon EC2 and Filezilla. When I try to connect to the server, I am getting an error message: "Error:    Network error: Connection refused"

[image]

The problem is that I can't get a complete tutorial on how to use Filezilla with Amazon EC2. I try to follow the steps in this post: [Connect to Amazon EC2 file directory using Filezilla and SFTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16744863/connect-to-amazon-ec2-file-directory-using-filezilla-and-sftp), but it is still not working.

**What I have done so far:**

1. I add the following ports in the Security Group of my instance:

[image]

2. Turn off temporarily Windows firewall on my Remote machine (I am
   using Windows Server 2016 Datacenter) and on my pc also.

**Filezilla:**

3. I imported my key file in Settings > Connection > SFTP, the file has
        .pem as extension, I renamed it to .ppk before import but it is
        still not working. I also try to convert it using PuttyGen but it
        does not work.

**Questions:**

1. Are my ports correct in the inbound rules ?
2. Do I need to run Filezilla server (available in Xampp control panel)
   on my remote machine ?

**Additional Info**:
When I try connecting to the server using FTP(insecure):

[image]

I get the following error message:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using username:

username = ec2-user