# How to retrieve source code from Amazon Elastic Compute?

Tags: amazon-ec2

My application is hosted on Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud by the developer. I need to retrieve the source code for my web application. I am a new user so I need to know how can i download the source codes in my local host.

Comment: Assuming you have access to SSH into the EC2 instances, you can use GIT to first add your repository to GitHub account and then zip the code from there. OR you can Connect to Amazon EC2 file directory using Filezilla and SFTP. In that case this answer may help you:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16744863/connect-to-amazon-ec2-file-directory-using-filezilla-and-sftp

Answer (score 0):

You need to log into the instance using SSH. If you're familiar with SSH then you can SCP from your local machine.

Of you're not familiar, you can use Systems Manager and transfer the data to S3 then download from there:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/systems-manager-ssh-vpc-resources/